# Detecting airplay mirroring enabled in IOS App

Tags: ios, airplay

Is it possible for my IOS app to determine whether the airplay mirroring in enabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting iOS AirPlay screen mirroring capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935144/detecting-ios-airplay-screen-mirroring-capabilities)